# PHP serialization handler issue

Tags: php

PHP is using some specific serliazisation algorithm for encoding session data. I'm trying to override it by setting `session.serialize_handler` to `php_serialize` as documented [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler). It's not working and causing this error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorOrWarningException' with message 'ini_set(): Cannot find serialization handler 'php_serialize'' in /path:10
```

Why does it not find this setting if it's documented on php.net itself? Bottom line is that I need to save PHP's session data in JSON format in the database to share it with another platform.

Comment: `php_serialize` is only available from PHP 5.5.4 and onwards, as documented in your link.

Comment: Try to upgrade your php version 5.5.4 above to make it workable:)

Comment: Thanks, I've totally missed it. Ironically, I'm on 5.5.3 at the moment.

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php though

Comment: @Caballero Previously I too tried with namespace I get fatal error. Finally i read out the documentation again. Namespace works only php version 5.3.